# Table sorting by hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, tablesorter

I want to sort a table by price, but prices may appear inside a string:

e.g.: `Starting from $75`, `today only: $25`, `$100`, etc.

The only constant pattern is that the sorted value will always have `$` sign next to it.

At first, I've tried using the `tablesorter` jquery plugin, added a custom parser and reached [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/5673/).

But in order to use this method, it seems like I must enable the user the option to sort the table on his own later, which I don't want. Otherwise, if I Set all sorters to `false`, I can't sort it using the custom `money` parser.

So then, I started using hidden input that will contain only the numeric value that I want to get sorted. I don't know if it's a good practice, and also it requires me to add it as additional line to each relevant cell, which I would rather pass, as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7Ybw/17/).

And then I realized it's probably unnecessary at all to use the `tablesorter` plugin, as I can reach this results with much less code, as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZcQD/7/), which is my current code.

**Current code:**

**JS:**

```
function sortNum(a, b) {
    var aVal = 1 * $(a).find("input[name='price']").val();
    var bVal = 1 * $(b).find("input[name='price']").val();

    if(aVal == 0)
        return 1;
    else if(bVal == 0)
        return -1;
    else
        return aVal < bVal ? -1 : 1;
}
function sortTheTable(){
    $(function() {
        var elems = $.makeArray($('tr:has(.sort)').remove())
        elems.sort(sortNum);
        console.log(elems);
        $("#sortme").append($(elems));
    });
}

sortTheTable();
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="sortme">
    <tr>
        <th>name</td>
        <th>price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td class="sort">Only 5 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="5"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">$3 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="3"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="sort">$8 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="8"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="sort">0 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="0"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>h</td>
        <td class="sort">2 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="2"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>p</td>
        <td class="sort">6 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="6"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">20 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="20"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">0 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="0"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Main question:**

How to make the code sort only rows that have hidden input (or whatever better practice that you suggest to make the code better as possible), instead of by cells that have the `class="sort"` (I don't want to use this class).

I tried switching:

`var elems = $.makeArray($('tr:has(.sort)').remove())`

Into:

`var elems = $.makeArray($('tr:has(input[name='price'])').remove())`

But it doesn't work.

Also, in general, if you can come up with a better method to do what I'm trying to do, without having to use hidden inputs, let me know. Is it an acceptable practice? usually I only see inputs used in forms.

Answer (score 1):

Select only `tr` elements that have the hidden `input` as you tried `$('tr:has(input[name="price"])')` and change your `sortNum` function to:

```
function sortNum(a, b) {
    var aVal = 1 * $(a).find("input[name='price']").val();
    var bVal = 1 * $(b).find("input[name='price']").val();

    return aVal - bVal;
}
```

This should work just fine: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZcQD/8/)

The compare function `sortNum` you used in [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is wrong as the documentation states:

> If *compareFunction* is supplied, the array elements are sorted
>   according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are
>   two elements being compared, then:
>
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort `a` to a lower index than `b`, i.e. a comes first.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave `a` and `b` unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
>     elements.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort `b` to a lower index than `a`.
> - `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements `a` and `b` as its two arguments. **If
>     inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined**.

But your function does not respect this rules. For example, if `a = b` you return `1` insetad of `0`, as they are equals.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal using only jQuery and js sort to minimize the code and speed up is:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#sortme tr:has(input[name="price"])').sort(function(a, b) {
    return 1 * $(a).find("input[name='price']").val() - 1 * $(b).find("input[name='price']").val();
  }).appendTo('#sortme');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<table id="sortme">
    <tr>
        <th>name</td>
        <th>price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td class="sort">Only 5 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="5"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">$3 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="3"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="sort">$8 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="8"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td class="sort">0 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="0"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>h</td>
        <td class="sort">2 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="2"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>p</td>
        <td class="sort">6 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="6"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">20 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="20"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td class="sort">0 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="0"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! can you explain what makes this faster?

Comment: Like you can see in one line I put all your code: So all it's demanded completely to jQuery selectors